# how can I use Intl.dateTimeFormat to display the value of a timestamp across four time zones in standard time?

Tags: javascript, date

I have timestamps that I'd like to be able to display in a user given time zone. I'm noticing that even when using a dedicated library like date-fns-tz it seems to return values that don't make sense.

Under the hood they apparently use Intl, and when I use that module it doesn't seem to provide the correct value.

```js
const zones = ['PST', 'MST', 'CST', 'EST'];
zones.forEach((timeZone) =>
  console.log(
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
      timeZone,
      timeStyle: 'full',
      dateStyle: 'full',
    }).format(1588743894000)
  )
);
```

This outputs:

```
Tuesday, May 5, 2020 at 10:44:54 PM Pacific Daylight Time
Tuesday, May 5, 2020 at 10:44:54 PM GMT-07:00
Wednesday, May 6, 2020 at 12:44:54 AM Central Daylight Time
Wednesday, May 6, 2020 at 12:44:54 AM GMT-05:00
```

But shouldn't this be four different values?

Comment: Civil timezone names and abbreviations are neither standardised nor unique. Most systems use POSIX offsets (±HH:mm:ss), military designators (A-Z) or IANA representative locations (region/city). The *Intl* object uses IANA representative locations, which include historic and daylight saving changes over time and are more or less the *de facto* standard for computer and other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the three-letter timezone abbreviations, what it is expecting is an IANA timezone (https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-time-zone-names). I believe it is flummoxed because you're passing standard timezones for a daylight time.

```
const zones = ["America/Los_Angeles", "America/Denver", "America/Chicago", "America/New_York"]
zones.forEach(timeZone => 
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { timeZone, timeStyle: "full", dateStyle: "full"}).format(1588743894000)));
```

This yields:

```
Tuesday, May 5, 2020 at 10:44:54 PM Pacific Daylight Time
Tuesday, May 5, 2020 at 11:44:54 PM Mountain Daylight Time
Wednesday, May 6, 2020 at 12:44:54 AM Central Daylight Time
Wednesday, May 6, 2020 at 1:44:54 AM Eastern Daylight Time
```

Comment: As an added note supported values can be seen using [Intl.supportedValuesOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/supportedValuesOf). ie. `console.log(Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone'));`

Comment: I wonder what it thought I was passing...  Thank you!

Comment: I know, right? I was surprised it worked as well as it did. It was trying...